# Required test plan for chat application using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am getting a Response code 401 and Response Message as Unauthorized while recorded script through JMeter

Sampler Result

> Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
>   Sample Start: 2016-07-19 14:40:53 IST
>   Load time: 285
>   Connect Time: 0
>   Latency: 283
>   Size in bytes: 534
>   Headers size in bytes: 456
>   Body size in bytes: 78
>   Sample Count: 1
>   Error Count: 1
>   Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
>   Response code: 401
>   Response message: Unauthorized

Response headers:

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>   Date: Tue, 19 Jul 2016 09:10:53 GMT
>   Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Cache-Control: no-store
>   x-ca-err: 992
>   Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
>   P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy.  Please see   http://www.networkfleet.com/privacy-policy/ for the official privacy policy."
>   Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=99
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Content-Length: 78
>   Content-Encoding: gzip

HTTPSampleResult fields:

> ContentType: application/json;charset=UTF-8
>   DataEncoding: UTF-8

Response Data

```
{
  "error":"invalid_request",
  "error_description":"Validation error"
}
```

Comment: Your application doesn't like what you are sending to it. Most likely your app has an authentication token, or a cookie, which must be dynamically retrieved from server response and then supplied with following requests.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on authentication information your application expects you can work it around in several ways:

1. Basic HTTP (looks like modal pop-up window when you're trying to open protected page). To bypass it add [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) to your Test Plan and provide credentials there. See [How to Use HTTP Basic Authentication in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) article for details.
2. Missing or incorrect parameter. Some applications use dynamic parameters for security purposes and if you recorded it - it is hard-coded and cannot be replayed successfully. Try recording your application 2 times and inspect request details for differences. If there are any - work them around using [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor)